# Generate a date range of the latest 2 weeks?

Tags: php, date

I want to generate 2 DATETIME which represent the latest 2 weeks starting from sunday to saturday 2x, It shouldn't include the current incomplete week.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't even have an idea how to do that other than including the current week..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something to begin with:

```
$timestamp_end = strtotime("last Saturday");
$timestamp_start = $timestamp_end - 14 * 24 * 3600;
```

Comment: note that this assumes no DST changes, etc. in those 2 weeks.

Answer (score 4):

Something to work from, using the wonderful `DateTime` classes:

```
<?php

$end = new DateTime('last Sunday'); // note that the end date is excluded from a DatePeriod
$start = clone $end;
$start->sub(new DateInterval('P14D'));

foreach (new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end) as $day) {
    echo $day->format('r'), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$lastSaturday = strtotime("last Saturday");
//$firstSunday = $lastSaturday - (13 * 24 * 3600);
for($n=13;$n>=0;$n--){
    $timeArray[] = $lastSaturday - ($n * 24 * 3600);
    $dateTime[] = date('Y-m-d H:i l', $lastSaturday - ($n * 24 * 3600));
}
?>
<pre>
<?php
print_r($dateTime);
?>
</pre>
```